# Including user-created modules when compiling with PyInstaller

Tags: python, import, package, pyinstaller

I've built an app with a working gui (built with tkinter).
The gui calls the main script which calls the other component scripts.

I tried compiling th gui script with pyinstaller and the compilation process is effortless.

But the exe doesn't do anything.
If i run the exe, the cmd window pops up for a split second and closes immediately.

Here's the gui script for reference. Running the script from CMD works perfectly but the .exe does not

```
from tkinter import *
import generator


root = Tk()

def get_data():
    #request and pick matric number
    label1 = Label(root, text="ENTER MATRIC NO")
    label1.pack()
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e1.pack()

    #request and pick issued to
    label2 = Label(root, text="WHO IS IT ISSUED TO?")
    label2.pack()
    e2 = Entry(root)
    e2.insert(0, string="Seperate address lines by commas")
    e2.pack()

    #request and pick transcript type
    label3 = Label(root, text="TRANSCRIPT TYPE: S OR L OR I? ")
    label3.pack()
    e3 = Entry(root)
    e3.pack()

    def save1():
        mat_no = e1.get()
        return mat_no
    
    def save2():
        issued_to = e2.get()
        return issued_to

    def save3():
        transcript_type = e3.get()
        return transcript_type

    def generate(mat_no, issued_to, transcript_type):
        generator.gen(mat_no, issued_to, transcript_type) #calls main function

    generate_button = Button(root, text="GENERATE", command= lambda: generate(save1(), save2(), save3()), fg="blue")
    generate_button.pack()

def gui():
    root.title("Transcript Generator")
    #get and save required data

    mylabel = Label(root, text="WELCOME TO THE TRANSCRIPT GENERATOR")
    mylabel.pack()

    start_button = Button(root, text="CLICK TO START", command=get_data, fg="blue")
    start_button.pack()

    quit_button = Button(root, text = "EXIT PROGRAM", command=root.quit)
    quit_button.pack

    root.mainloop()

def main():
    gui()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Create the exe in console mode and run it from CMD. This may show a helpful error message.

Comment: Just tried that no error message. But sometime earlier (a few hours ago), I got an error along the lines of can't import generator because no such module exists